# org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus and org.springframework.http.HttpStatus does not exist

Tags: java, xml, maven, spring-boot, dependencies

I'm working on a CRUD Web Application, using the following instruction:

https://www.javaguides.net/2019/02/spring-boot-2-angular-7-crud-example-tutorial.html
As the guide said I used spring framework for the back end, 
while I was compilating the file: ResourceNotFoundException.java

### it gives me back this error:

```
C:\Users\Roberto\Desktop\ springboot2-jpa-crud-example\src\test\java\net\guides\springboot2\springboot2jpacrudexample\exception>javac ResourceNotFoundException.java
    ResourceNotFoundException.java:2: error: package org.springframework does not exist
    import org.springframework.http;

                          ^
ResourceNotFoundException.java:3: error: package org.springframework.http does not exist
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
                               ^
ResourceNotFoundException.java:4: error: package org.springframework.web.bind does not exist
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation;
                                   ^
ResourceNotFoundException.java:5: error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
                                              ^
ResourceNotFoundException.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
 ^
  symbol: class ResponseStatus
5 errors
```

---

I notice ont he web that the problem could be given by the maven version o npm version (npm -version 6.9.0 |   mvn -v Apache Maven 3.6.1)and could be solved by adding some dependecies to the pom.xlm file, i post the pom.xlm file here:

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>net.guides.springboot2</groupId>
<artifactId>springboot2-jpa-crud-example</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>springboot2-jpa-crud-example</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
       <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>
```

If someone could help me  it would be fantastic thx^^

__________________________*UPDATE*_______________________

### As comment bellow said i just try to add this code to my pom.xlm file

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
<version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
```

---

### but  after compile it didnt work

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Roberto/Desktop/ springboot2-jpa-crud- 
example/src/test/java/net/guides/springboot2/springboot2jpacrudexample/
exception 
/ResourceNotFoundException.java:[6,8] duplicate class: 
com.companyname.springbootcrudrest.exception.ResourceNotFoundException
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Roberto/Desktop/ springboot2-jpa-crud- 
example/src/test/java/net/guides/springboot2
/springboot2jpacrudexample/controller 
/EmployeeController.java:[20,66] cannot access 
net.guides.springboot2.springboot2jpacrudexample.
exception.ResourceNotFoundException
bad source file: C:\Users\Roberto\Desktop\ springboot2-jpa-crud- 
example\src\test\java\net\guides\springboot2
\springboot2jpacrudexample\exception\ 
ResourceNotFoundException.java
file does not contain class 
net.guides.springboot2.springboot2jpacrudexample.
exception.ResourceNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this dependency to your `POM.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i just do it, it didnt fix the problem